# How to change colour of a spawned image using Arcore Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I am using arcore and spawning a prefab on tap to ground plane. But now I am trying to change the colour of the prefab in runtime using a colour picker.

Could someone tell me how to assign a colour to the spawned object in runtime?

I am using the object manipulation scene of arcore

Answer (score 0):

**Note the OP asked about Unity - the below is Android only. I'll leave it here in case it is of use to anyone but it does not answer the question for Unity.**

At the time I was looking at a similar requirement the best practice appeared to be to copy, recolour and then replace the renderable.

There may be other ways to do this in later releases, but the below is tested and works.

```js
                //Now highlight the new current selected node
                ModelRenderable highlightedAndyRenderable = andyRenderable.makeCopy();
                highlightedAndyRenderable.getMaterial().setFloat3("baseColorTint", new Color(android.graphics.Color.rgb(255,0,0)));
                hitNode.setRenderable(highlightedAndyRenderable);
                currentSelectedAnchorNode = (AnchorNode) hitNode;
```

Comment: But the Instantiated andyprefab wouldnt be available in another script no? that is the colour picker script ? @Mick

Comment: @JerinCherian - apologies, I missed the unity TAG. The above is Android Java specific. I'll update and leave it was a note but your question is still open so hopefully someone can give you a Unity specie answer.